How do I add a column cell value per row?
Here is my gsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EnAJt4K1lHhtQrjulEWjGejFcNwnqKK-o-GBXZvro2k/edit?usp=sharing
In B2 of the RepData <tab>, I have pulled in all the data from the 2 reps (Joe & Robert).
={ARRAYFORMULA(Joe!A2:C4);ARRAYFORMULA(Robert!A2:C4)}

However I would like for each line I pull from the rep's data to first prepend the rep's name.
How can I do that?
Thank you, EJ
I tried:
={{"Joe";ARRAYFORMULA(Joe!A2:C4)};{"Robert";ARRAYFORMULA(Robert!A2:C4)}}

I can't figure out how to insert a (column/cell) value per arrayformula row

Figured it out:  =sort({arrayformula(if(Joe!A2:A="", "", "Joe")),ARRAYFORMULA(Joe!A2:C);arrayformula(if(Robert!A2:A="", "", "Robert")),ARRAYFORMULA(Robert!A2:C)}, 1, 0)

try:
=INDEX(QUERY(LET(j, Joe!A2:C4, r, Robert!A2:C4, 
 {IF(TOCOL(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(j),,9^9)))="",,"Joe"), j; 
  IF(TOCOL(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(r),,9^9)))="",,"robert"), r}), 
  "where Col1 is not null", ))


or:
=QUERY({QUERY(Joe!A2:C4,    "select 'Joe',   A,B,C label 'Joe'''", ); 
        QUERY(Robert!A2:C4, "select 'Robert',A,B,C label 'Robert'''", )}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", )



tocol and transpose - thank you!
